# Help translating this stotram

Tags: shiva, translation-request, stotra

At the end of Dakshinamurty Stotram is written :

> Angushtha Tarjanee Yoga Mudraa Vyaajena Dehinaam Shrutyartham Brahma
> Jeevaikyam Darshayanno Vataat Shivaha (...)  Mounavyaakhyaa prakatita
> para brahma tattvam yuvaanam varshish thaante vasad rushiganaih
> aavrutam brahmanishthaih AAchaaryendram karakalita chinmudram aananda
> rupam  Svaatmaaraam Mudita vadanam Dakshinamoorthy mee-dey

Can someone help to translate correctly this passage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from [Dakshinamoorthy stotra](http://dharmakirtan.blogspot.com/2013/07/dakshinamurthys-stotram-explained-by.html)

> Mauna-Vyaakhyaa Prakattita Para-Brahma-Tattvam Yuvaanam
>
> Varssisstthaam-Te Vasad Rssigannauh Aavrtam Brahma-Nisstthaih |
>
> Aacaarye[a-I]ndram Kara-Kalita Cin-Mudram-Aananda-Muurtim
>
> Sva-[A]atmaaraamam Mudita-Vadanam Dakssinnaamuurti-Miidde ||

Meaning:

1: (Salutations to Sri Dakshinamurthy) Whose Exposition through Profound Silence is Awakening the Knowledge of the Supreme Brahman in the Hearts of His Disciples; Who is Himself Youthful ...

2: ... but is Sitting Surrounded by Old and Great Sages who are Devoted to Brahman,

3: The Hands of the Supreme Spiritual Teacher is Forming the Cin-Mudra (gesture of the Knowledge of Brahman) and Whose Appearance is Still and Blissful,

4: Who is Rejoicing in His Own Self which is reflected on His Blissful Face; Salutations to Sri Dakshinamurthy.

> Angushtha-tarjanee yogamudra vyaajaena dachinaam Shrutyartham
> brahmajeevaikyam darshartham brahmajeevaikyam Darshayanno(a)
> vataachchivaha

The lord dakishnamurthy holds his thumb and index finger (tarjanee)
And exhibits yoga mudra, which convey his form that he is a perfect yogi
When one hears him, it appears as though he is merged with Brahman.
When he Is seen he appears to be the very manifestation of lord shiva.

Comment: perfect, thank you. is missing only this part Angushtha Tarjanee Yoga Mudraa Vyaajena Dehinaam Shrutyartham Brahma Jeevaikyam Darshayanno Vataat Shivaha

Comment: I have added the meaning of the text

Comment: Thank you! perfect